# PHP Send mail error

Tags: php, phpmailer

Please help me I am New in PHP and since last 5 Hours i am try to semd mail and now really tired. Thanks.

**Here is my code. I am using Gmail account.**

```
include("class.phpmailer.php");
//include("class.smtp.php"); // optional, gets called from within class.phpmailer.php if not already loaded

$mail             = new PHPMailer();

$body             = $mail->getFile('contents.html');
$body             = eregi_replace("[\]",'',$body);

$mail->IsSMTP();
$mail->SMTPAuth   = true;                  // enable SMTP authentication
$mail->SMTPSecure = "ssl";                 // sets the prefix to the servier
$mail->Host       = "smtp.gmail.com";      // sets GMAIL as the SMTP server
$mail->Port       = 465;                   // set the SMTP port for the GMAIL server

$mail->Username   = "hussaintalha@gmail.com";  // GMAIL username
$mail->Password   = "xxxxxxxx";            // GMAIL password

$mail->AddReplyTo("hussaintalha@gmail.com","First Last");

$mail->From       = "hussaintalha@gmail.com.com";
$mail->FromName   = "First Last";

$mail->Subject    = "PHPMailer Test Subject via gmail";

//$mail->Body       = "Hi,<br>This is the HTML BODY<br>";                      //HTML Body
$mail->AltBody    = "To view the message, please use an HTML compatible email viewer!"; // optional, comment out and test
$mail->WordWrap   = 50; // set word wrap

$mail->MsgHTML($body);

$mail->AddAddress("hussaintalha@gmail.com", "John Doe");

$mail->AddAttachment("images/phpmailer.gif");             // attachment

$mail->IsHTML(true); // send as HTML

if(!$mail->Send()) {
  echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
} else {
  echo "Message sent!";
}
?>
```

When I run my file I get This Error:

> Warning: fopen(contents.html)
>   [function.fopen]: failed to open
>   stream: No such file or directory in
>   D:\xampplite\htdocs\WebEng\class.phpmailer.php
>   on line 1870
>
> Warning: fsockopen()
>   [function.fsockopen]: unable to
>   connect to ssl://smtp.gmail.com:465
>   (Unable to find the socket transport
>   "ssl" - did you forget to enable it
>   when you configured PHP?) in
>   D:\xampplite\htdocs\WebEng\class.smtp.php
>   on line 122 Mailer Error: SMTP Error:
>   Could not connect to SMTP host.

Comment: It's not polite to shout. The correct way to emphasize something is to put it in bold or italics. However, I don't think what you wrote in all caps needs to be emphasized.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all when you get error messages then that's great! Because in 90% of the cases you find that others have had them too and therefore you'll find plenty of information on the internet about this error message.

So step 1 when getting an error message you don't know yet is always open google and copy paste it there. But, take out any paths or other things which are uniquely connected to your system.

Then about your errors. Especially xampp light doesn't support SSL. Maybe you try an easier sendmail example first. Like a very small one and then increase it step by step.
That's what I always do, when I don't know why something doesn't work. I start with one line and see what it does, then I add another and so forth.

Let's say you start with this and see if it works:

```
<?php

include("class.phpmailer.php");

$mail             = new PHPMailer();

$mail->IsSMTP();
$mail->SMTPAuth   = true;                  // enable SMTP authentication
$mail->Host       = "smtp.gmail.com";      // sets GMAIL as the SMTP server
$mail->Port       = 465;                   // set the SMTP port for the GMAIL server
$mail->Username   = "hussaintalha@gmail.com";  // GMAIL username
$mail->Password   = "xxxxxxxx";            // GMAIL password

$mail->From       = "hussaintalha@gmail.com";
$mail->Subject    = "PHPMailer Test Subject via gmail";
$mail->Body       = "Hi, this is a test";           
$mail->AddAddress("hussaintalha@gmail.com", "Hussain");

$mail->send();
?>
```

oh, and btw. your mail from has a .com too many!

Comment: I tried to run your code and it gave me no error but i didnt get any mail as well. where can I check is there any Queue Folder in xampp where we can check either code its working or not such like we have in IIS. Thanks for your very helpful reply please guide me further thanks.

Comment: do you have a hosting somewhere? where you could test the code online...
xampp comes with Mercury (Mail Server) I don't know about the lite version. I normally use Mercury and just forward everything to tester@localhost for which I create a pop account in my e-mail client.

Comment: no actually i dont have any hosting. Then How to know?? Any way Thanks alot for your help i will check if couldnt get then will get back to you.

Comment: of course it depends on your provenance what's cheap and what's not but shared hosting accounts are considered extremely cheap! if you're serious with learning PHP and the like you should consider getting one of those for a starter!

Answer (score 4):

You PHP installation (XAMPP, by the looks of it) does not support SSL. Ensure that the line

```
extension=php_openssl.dll
```

is *not* commented out in your php.ini, restart Apache, and if that still doesn't work try overwriting (or copying) ssleay32.dll and libeay32.dll from your PHP directory into Apache's binary (.exe) directory then restart Apache.